# Search table cell text against array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a table with a bunch of data in it. Currently, my code compares textfield input to the data in the table. If there's a match, it will show that particular table row. Here's my code:

```
  $(document).on('keyup','#filterText',function(){
    
    $('.all').hide();  // hide everything
    $('tfoot').hide(); // hide everything
      
    var s = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); //get input string
    
    if(s==''){$('.all').show(); $('tfoot').show();}; // if no input then show everything
    

    $('#report tbody tr td').each(function(i,td) {
      
      //go through each table cell and compare
      if($(td).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(s)!==-1){
       $(td).closest('tr').show(); // show table row
      }             
      
    });
    
  }); //.but_filterText
```

This works great. But now, I need to modify this so that a user could do multiple searches at the same time, separated by a comma. So here's what I did and nothing happens:

```
$(document).on('keyup','#filterText',function(){
  $('.all').hide();  
  $('tfoot').hide();
  
  var s = $(this).val().toLowerCase().split(',');

  if(s === undefined || s.length == 0){
    $('.all').show(); $('tfoot').show();
  };

  $('#report tbody tr td').each(function(i,td) {
    if(s.indexOf($(td).text().toLowerCase())!==-1){
        $(td).closest('tr').show();
    }
  });

}); //.but_filterText
```

Seems like it should work but can't get it going. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks the issue is because in the input field you type `space` after `comma`, e.g. `text 1, text 2` instead of `text 1,text 2`

i made a small (similar to yours code) example: (in this example you can type with or without `space`, since it will be replaced)

```
$('[name="search"]').on('keyup', function() {

  var $tds = $('td');

  var s = this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\,\s/,',').split(','); 
  // consider replacing comma+space (/\,\s/) with just a comma

  // and also i would recommend using filter function for finding matches,
  // it will return an array of matched elements, empty if there is no match
  $tds = $tds.filter(function(i, td) {
    return s.indexOf($(td).text().toLowerCase()) >=0;
  });

  $tds.addClass('selected');
});
```

Here is the jsfillde - http://jsfiddle.net/zqdbso1w/1/

**UPDATE** (based on your comment)

Here is the jsfillde - http://jsfiddle.net/zqdbso1w/3/

simply make second iteration to seek for a substring in haystack

```
$('[name="search"]').on('keyup', function() {
    var $tds = $('td');
    var s = this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\,\s/,',').split(',');
  $tds.removeClass('selected');
  $tds.each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        var r = s.filter( function(t) {
        if (!t.length) return false;
            return text.indexOf(t) >= 0;
        });

    if (r.length) $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

});
```

**UPDATE** regex should be global, and remove all spaces after all commas

Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zqdbso1w/4/

Comment: looks like my earlier comment didn't go through. Does that replace remove all spacing?

Comment: It removes only comma+space

Comment: just noticed another thing... works a little, but not all the way. As I type the word "T--e-x-t", everything should be highlighted because it is matching, BUT it's only until after i hit space "1" that it highlights. I'm looking at your code... don't really understand it, but it looks like it should highlight as i type but it doesn't. How can I change that behavior?

Comment: That’s another question, because i took your sample which only checks if there is a full word match ‘[“word”,”word two”].indexOf(“word”)’, because its an array of strings. And when you check using indexof for a single string, the string is being “exploded” to an array of letters of that string, e.g: ‘[“w”,”o”,”r”,”d”].indexOf(“w”)’ gives 0.  So what are you saying now is totally different story.

Comment: hmmmm.... i see what your saying there. I guess that wasn't my original intention. My original code check not individual words but letters as you type. What I was intending to do is keep that functionality, but if a user adds a comma to take that into account too. How can I make that happen?

Comment: i made an update, check the new example, the idea is to iterate through haystack array

Comment: Give me a second... I'm trying to understand the code and adopt it. brb.

Comment: so... still trying to wrap my head around this thing. Love it cause i'm learning. On another note, I've adopted it for use with my code and I'm having an issue. Everything works great until you add a 3rd parameter. From what i see in the code, it should work fine, but "tex", "text 1, text 2" work, but "text 1, text 2, text 3" only highlights 2 of them. Same behavior happens in your updated jsfiddle. check it out.

Comment: see the update, there was a rookie mistake, where replace didn't get rid of the last space

Comment: that worked! still don't get why making it global fixed it but it works!

Comment: it means that the regex will go from start to the end and not return after first match, if you want to learn how to use regular expressions, this website is very helpful - https://regex101.com/

Comment: don't forget to check the answer tho)